# How to gather data in my case using gather_nd in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need to gather some data from Tensor, I used `gather_nd`. Now code is above

```
import tensorflow as tf

indices = [[[0, 4], [0, 1], [0, 6], [0, 2]],
           [[1, 1], [1, 4], [1, 0], [1, 9]],
           [[2, 5], [2, 1], [2, 9], [2, 6]]]

params = [[4,6,3,6,7,8,4,5,3,8], [9,5,6,2,6,5,1,9,6,4], [4,6,6,1,3,2,6,7,1,8]]
output = tf.gather_nd(params, indices)

sess = tf.Session()
print sess.run(output)
```

The output is

```
[[7 6 4 3]
 [5 6 9 4]
 [2 6 8 6]]
```

Yep, that's what I want. I want to take out the values located at 4,1,6,2 in params[0]. They are 7, 6, 4, 3 because params[0][4] = 7, params[0][1] = 6, params[0][6] = 4, params[0][2] = 3.

However, `tf.gather_nd` only receives a indices like above. Now my raw_indices is like,

```
[[4, 1, 6, 2],
 [1, 4, 0, 9],
 [5, 1, 9, 6]]
```

How can I transfer the `raw_indices` to `indices` in tensorflow? Yes, I have to do this step in tensor graph since `raw_indices` is generated in the middle of the graph.

Comment: See also: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5328

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mixture of tf.range() and some tiling seems to work:

```
def index_matrix_to_pairs(index_matrix):
  replicated_first_indices = tf.tile(
      tf.expand_dims(tf.range(tf.shape(index_matrix)[0]), dim=1), 
      [1, tf.shape(index_matrix)[1]])
  return tf.pack([replicated_first_indices, index_matrix], axis=2)

start = [[4, 1, 6, 2],
 [1, 4, 0, 9],
 [5, 1, 9, 6]]
with tf.Session():
  print(index_matrix_to_pairs(start).eval())
```

Gives:

```
[[[0 4]
  [0 1]
  [0 6]
  [0 2]]

 [[1 1]
  [1 4]
  [1 0]
  [1 9]]

 [[2 5]
  [2 1]
  [2 9]
  [2 6]]]
```

It's just generating the first part of each pair with a tiled tf.range() op, then packing that with the specified indices.

Comment: Thanks! I got it. I just temporarily flatten the params and indices and use tf.gather(). But your solution is pretty good.

Comment: Sad, when I use gather_nd in my code, it gives "NotImplementedError: Gradient for gather_nd is not implemented". Maybe I have to use tf.gather again.

Comment: Oh, unfortunate. Hopefully that gradient gets implemented soon.

Comment: the gradient's been added