# Merging only some channels in keras using concatenate

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I'd to concatenate only selected channels in keras  but when I do, it shows as error.

I tried to get channels of interest and used concatenate function to merge two outputs.

```
def cifar10ClassifierTransfer(input_img, conv2_high):

  # Add additional inputs to 

  conv1_1 = (Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(weight_decay), input_shape=x_train.shape[1:], activation='elu'))(input_img)
  conv1_2 = BatchNormalization()(conv1_1)
  conv2_1 = (Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding='same', activation= 'elu',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(weight_decay)))(conv1_2)
  conv2_high = conv2_high[:,:,:,[1,2,3]]
  concat_layer = keras.layers.merge.Concatenate(axis=3)([conv2_1,conv2_high])

  flat = Flatten()(concat_layer)
  out = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(flat)

  return out
```

I expected the number of channels to increase. If i do not specify which channels I want to merge, it works fine but when I select channels, it gives the following error

```
TypeError: Only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), tf.newaxis (`None`) and scalar tf.int32/tf.int64 tensors are valid indices, got [1, 2, 3]
```

How can we choose the channels I want to concatenate rather than concatenating everything?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a slice as indicate by the error.

`conv2_high` can be rewritten as:

```
conv2_high = conv2_high[:,:,:,1:4]
```

You could also use [`tf.gather_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd) but the approach above is more readable IMO.

Comment: Thanks, What if my channels are not in sequence; if I want to do something like this - conv2_high = conv2_high[:,:,:,[1,4,5,11,20]]

Comment: Use `gather_nd` which works similarly to slides, though far from it's intuitiveness unluckily. I suppose you could use Python's ranges for first three dimensions (were each range is of size of that specific dimension) and use `[1,4,5,11,20]` as the last one. [Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40362011/how-to-gather-data-in-my-case-using-gather-nd-in-tensorflow) for intuitive explanation.